# How to return count:0 in an aggregation if there is no match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having an issues that I thought it would happen often, but I wasn't able to find enough information during my research.

My problem is that I expect the return of a query to have a given JSON format, but when the match filters out all documents, I get no json.

A simplified example: I would like to have the count if documents that match a given criteria, so I have the following query

```monodb
 db.collection.aggregate( [{ 
       $match: {
            type: /^1[.]2[.]3[.].*$/
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {$ifNull : ["$type", 0]}, 
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }]);
```

If I have at least one document that matches, then the query works:

```monodb
{ "_id" : "1.2.3", "count" : 44 }
```

If I have no documents, I would like to receive a json like this:

```monodb
{ "_id" : "1.5.3", "count" : 0 }
```

Is this possible?

ps: this is a simplified case, it would not be so easy to handle that on the application side, so I would rather try to adjust my query

Comment: No. It's not possible as you have formulated it. The aggregation pipeline can't produce a document from no document, it can only produce 1 or more documents from 1 or more documents.

Comment: Ok, that is a pitty, thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

If you can know beforehand the value of the key that you are searching for(i.e. `1.2.3`, `1.5.3` in your case), here is a workaround using `$facet`. It first tries to get the documents by `$match` and store them into an array named `results`. Depending on the `$size` of the `results` array, we either replace it with the `$group` result (when we have matched records); or replace it with a default count: 0 record with the key you specified.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "results": [
        {
          $match: {
            "type": <key you want to search>
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              $ifNull: [
                "$type",
                0
              ]
            },
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $gt: [
              {
                "$size": "$results"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": "$$ROOT",
          "else": {
            "results": [
              {
                "_id": <key you want to search>,
                "count": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$results"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$results"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kMfBjLEgFS9)